Probability infinite sum with coins and balls/bins
We flip a coin until obtain a tails. The number of flips it takes us to get the first tails, is the number of balls we are given (so if we get the first tails on the 5th flip, we get 5 balls). We randomly throw the balls into 3 bins labeled 1, 2, and 3. What's P(no bins are empty)?
My approach to answering this questions is as follows:
P(we get k balls) = (1/2) ^ k
P(no bins empty | heads on the kth flip) = (k-1 C 2) / (k+2 C 2).    I got this using stars and bars.
Therefore the total probability is the sum from k=3 to k=infinity (starting at 3 because by definition a bin will be empty if there are less than 3 balls thrown) of
(1/2)^k * (k-1 C 2) / (k+2 C 2)
Why is this not correct? I was told the answer is 1/10, but this isn't giving me 1/10.

You are not new user, can you use latex to format your equation?

You are using stars and bars which does not yield equiprobable outcomes, for computing probability.
Consider, for example that you throw $10$ balls into $3$ bins. You can understand that getting all balls into one bin is much less probable than a more even distribution. So you need to treat the problem as throwing distinct balls into distinct bins
If $k$ throws have taken place, there can be $3^k$ possible distributions, but distributions where no box is empty, using inclusion-exclusion, will be
$3^k - \binom312^k + \binom321^k = 3^k-3\cdot2^k +3$
and dividing by $2^k3^k$ for coin toss probability and total ways of filling boxes, we get
$$Pr = \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}{\frac{3^k-3\cdot2^k +3}{6^k}}=\frac1{10}$$
